# Showcase mode with shiny modules

Tags: r, shiny, shinymodules

I have a shiny application that uses shiny modules.
Each module lives in its own file in `modules/` and is sourced in `global.R`.
I also have a `DESCRIPTION` file which puts the shiny app into the showcase mode when deployed.

The problem is, that only code for global.R, server.R, and ui.R is displayed, which is helpful but does not show the full picture (eg showing that `mymodule_server("myid")` is run in server.R is helpful but I want to have the reactive elements  of the function shown and highlighted as its usual in the showcase mode).

Is this possible without dumping all modules in global.R?

Note that this is related to https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/3453

Comment: You can `source("./module.R", local=TRUE)` in server.R

Comment: Thats almost the answer... It seems that showcase mode only considers files in the current folder. when I include `modules/mod-mymodule.R` or `R/mod-mymodule.R` it is not recognized / displayed...